# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when accessing computed property of NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access

I have defined a class which has a calculated property. When I try to access the property in my code, I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. I set a breakpoint in the getter of the property and noticed it was never called. I don't know what is causing this. I can access other properties of the object.

Here is the code

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@objc(Person)

class Person: NSManagedObject {

    struct Keys {
        static let Name = "name"
        static let ProfilePath = "profile_path"
        static let Movies = "movies"
        static let ID = "id"
    }

    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var id: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var imagePath: String?
    @NSManaged var movies: [Movie]

    override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext     context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
    super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
}



init(dictionary: [String : AnyObject], context: NSManagedObjectContext) {

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: context)!

    super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)



    name = dictionary[Keys.Name] as! String
    id = dictionary[Keys.ID] as! Int
    imagePath = dictionary[Keys.ProfilePath] as? String
}

var image: UIImage? {
    get {
        return TheMovieDB.Caches.imageCache.imageWithIdentifier(imagePath)
    }

    set {
        TheMovieDB.Caches.imageCache.storeImage(image, withIdentifier: imagePath!)
    }
}
}
```

This is how I try to access the image property and get a

> Execution was interrupted, reason: 
>   EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)

When I do `actor.image`.
`actor` is an object of `Person` class and is properly initialized. 
I put a breakpoint in the getter for image property and it was never called.

```
if let localImage = actor.image {
            cell.actorImageView.image = localImage
        } else if actor.imagePath == nil || actor.imagePath == "" {
            cell.actorImageView.image = UIImage(named: "personNoImage")
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add image as a transient attribute to your CoreData model?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I didn't add image as a transient attribute, I wanted it to be a calculated property. I just figured out the problem, I had not set the class for the entity in the data model inspector.

Answer (score 3):

I just figured out the problem, I had not set the class for the entity in the data model inspector. That solved it